# Android volley recyclerview not showing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I spent a lot of time debugging this code but unfortunately could not find the bug, can someone help me find the issue in this code. I am not able to see data on the activity page. Although I have found the I am getting response data from the server.

**Activity Class**

```
public class SelectServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_service);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.select_service_rv);

        String serviceTypeId = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppConstants.SELECTED_SERVICE_TYPE_ID);

        getProductDetailsByProductId(serviceTypeId);
    }

    private void getProductDetailsByProductId(String serviceTypeId) {

        final List<SelectServiceBean> selectServiceList = new ArrayList<>();
        final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                APIEndpoints.SERVICE_LIST_URI + serviceTypeId,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    selectServiceList.add(DatabaseObjectsMapper.selectServiceBeanMapper((JSONObject) response.get(i)));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SelectServiceActivity.this, "Something went wrong : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(new SelectServiceAdapter(getApplicationContext(),selectServiceList));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SelectServiceActivity.this, "No Response From Server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(SelectServiceActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(SelectServiceActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class SelectServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<SelectServiceBean> selectServiceList;

    public SelectServiceAdapter(final Context context, final List<SelectServiceBean> selectServiceList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.selectServiceList = selectServiceList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_select_service, parent, false);
        return (new Item(row));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((Item) holder).serviceTypeIssue.setText(selectServiceList.get(position).getServiceTypeIssue());
        ((Item) holder).serviceTypeIssue.setText(selectServiceList.get(position).getServiceType());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return selectServiceList.size();
    }

    public static class Item extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView serviceTypeIssue;
        private TextView serviceType;

        public Item(View view) {
            super(view);
            serviceTypeIssue = view.findViewById(R.id.service_type_issue);

        }

    }
}
```

**Single View Item**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/service_type_issue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Sample text" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1sp"
        android:background="@color/lightGrey" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Recyclerview File**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/select_service_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: I see a missing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @AjilO. Black screen, SelectServiceActivity page loads with no data in it. I have already check there are no Visibility = Hidden / Gone

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh would not that create a new Adapter every time?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi that's the point , no need of `notify`

Comment: But is this the correct way? I think it would cause lagging on the UI thread.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi not the optimal (depends OP wants to manipulate views or not ) but the major issue is not performance in this question though

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Yes, I have data in the list I have seen while i was debugging it, but still I can not see the output :(

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh No output, still the same blank page

Answer (score 1):

From [`docs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager))

> A LayoutManager must be provided for RecyclerView to function.

You need to add the `layoutManager`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_service);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.select_service_rv);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        //^^^^^^^^^^^
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);    
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        String serviceTypeId = getIntent().getStringExtra(AppConstants.SELECTED_SERVICE_TYPE_ID);

        getProductDetailsByProductId(serviceTypeId);
    }
```

Improvement :

- Initialize `serviceType` in `Item` class and use it in `onBindViewHolder`

  ```
  public Item(View view) {
      super(view);
      serviceTypeIssue = view.findViewById(R.id.service_type_issue);
      serviceType      = view.findViewById(R.id.yourID);
      //^^^^^^^
  }
  ```
- Keep a reference to `new SelectServiceAdapter` so that later you can use `notify` functions for more optimal performance

  ```
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((Item)holder).serviceTypeIssue.setText(selectServiceList.get(position).getServiceTypeIssue());
    ((Item)holder).serviceType.setText(String.valueOf(selectServiceList.get(position).getServiceType()));
    //^^^^^^^^

  }
  ```

Comment: I am doing the same sir

Comment: you added the `layoutManager` as i pointed in the code above using `^^^^^` symbols

Comment: ((Item) holder).serviceTypeIssue.setText(selectServiceList.get(position).getServiceTypeIssue());

Comment: Recyclerview is still empty ?

Comment: This line from onBindViewHolder throwing an error  "Cannot find local variable 'holder'"

Comment: No Recyclerview has got one component displaied (a simple View 1sp line to seperate the contents)

Comment: you mean it is displaying only one item? if yes then as i said in my answer initialize `serviceType` and use it in `onbind`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149896/discussion-between-shamim-ahmad-and-pavneet-singh).